# Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "RNCViewPager" was not found in the UIMana

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I'm using react navigation's `material top tabs` and I'm getting this error `Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "RNCViewPager" was not found in the UIMana`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After couple hours of debugging, I solved the issue by doing the following

1. `react-native start --reset-cache`
2. uninstall the app from the device
3. `react-native run-android`